# Drag and drop 2 images to position them on a background and save them as 1 combined image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, imagemagick, gd

I have a PHP script using image processing GD/ImageMagick libraries on the server to generate text string on an image.

The image below shows a demo.

If I generated 2 lines of text as 2 images stacked on top of each other and used JavaScript to allow the user to frag and drop to re-arrange the positioning of the 2 images on a background image.

How could I go about saving a new image with the 2 text images in the position the user positioned them at?

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Below is a quick demo which generates a text on image like my demo image above.

I would load these images into a page using the user data to generate the text they want and then I will make them drag and drop with JavaScript.

When a submit button is clicked I need to get the coordinates of all the user generated text images and post them to a PHP script which would generate 1 new big image with all the text images on it and have them positioned where the user drag and dropped them into position.

1. I need help with getting the correct coordinates that would be needed.
2. Building a new image with all this using those coordinates on the PHP side.

Demo JSFiddle  loads an image text file like above. https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/nreme6yf/

```
<?php
/* Create some objects */
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'black' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(1000, 175, $pixel);

/*  text color */
//$draw->setFillColor('white');

/* Font properties */
if(isset($_GET['font'])){
    $fontName = $_GET['font'];
}else{
    $fontName = 'MISTRESS.ttf';
}

if(isset($_GET['font-size'])){
    $fontSize = $_GET['font-size'];
}else{
    $fontSize = 30;
}

if(isset($_GET['fill-color'])){
    $fillColor = $_GET['fill-color'];
}else{
    $fillColor = 'ffffff';
}

if(isset($_GET['stroke-color'])){
    $strokeColor = $_GET['stroke-color'];
}else{
    $strokeColor = '000000';
}

if(isset($_GET['stroke-width'])){
    $strokeWidth = $_GET['stroke-width'];
}else{
    $strokeWidth = 1;
}

if(isset($_GET['x'])){
    $x = $_GET['x'];
}else{
    $x = 10;
}
if(isset($_GET['y'])){
    $y = $_GET['y'];
}else{
    $y = 115;
}
if(isset($_GET['angle'])){
    $angle = $_GET['angle'];
}else{
    $angle = 0;
}

if(isset($_GET['text'])){
    $text = $_GET['text'];
}else{
    $text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
}




$draw->setFont('fonts-ttf/'.$fontName);
$draw->setFontSize($fontSize);
$draw->setFillColor('#'.$fillColor);
$draw->setStrokeColor(new ImagickPixel('#'.$strokeColor));
$draw->setStrokeWidth($strokeWidth);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, $x, $y, $angle, $text);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: can't the new html canvas element do things like this?

Comment: Are you asking how to do drag and drop? Or how to pass the coordinates back to the server? Or how to join images? Do you expect an answer using Javascript, or PHP? Are we supposed to use GD or ImageMagick?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can get 2 text string images like the one shown above on the screen and I can make them drag-able.  What I am wanting to do is create a new image that would have the 2 text images positioned to where the user dragged them to be at.  SO after dragging I would assume would need to get the coordinates of all text images on the screen and post to server and on the server create a new image positioning the  images using the coordinates....continue...

Comment: @MarkSetchell ...continued... I am not sure what exact coordinates I need or ho to get them.  On the server side if I have the coordinates I am not sure how to create a new image combining all this into 1.  I am updating my question to show my PHP code that generates the text images.

Comment: @Dagon I have never worked with Canvas before so I will look into that as a possibble solution too, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can take two images and lay them out at any desired position on a blank (transparent) canvas that is just large enough to hold them both. I have just hard-coded the image sizes and positions at the top and artificially generated a red and a blue image, but you would get them from the user's browser. So, your code would actually start after all my setup code where I have marked it.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f

<?php
// Set image widths and heights, and x,y coordinates of top-left corner
$im1_w=280;
$im1_h=150;
$im1_x=50;
$im1_y=100;
$im2_w=100;
$im2_h=220;
$im2_x=40;
$im2_y=70;

// Create images
$im1 = imagecreatetruecolor($im1_w,$im1_h);
$im1_colour = imagecolorallocate($im1, 255, 0, 0); // red
imagefilledrectangle($im1, 0, 0, $im1_w-1, $im1_h-1, $im1_colour);

$im2 = imagecreatetruecolor($im2_w,$im2_h);
$im2_colour = imagecolorallocate($im2, 0, 0, 255); // blue
imagefilledrectangle($im2, 0, 0, $im2_w-1, $im2_h-1, $im2_colour);

// Work out dimensions of output image   <=== YOUR CODE WOULD START FROM HERE
$out_w=max($im1_x+$im1_w,$im2_x+$im2_w);
$out_h=max($im1_y+$im1_h,$im2_y+$im2_h);

// Debug
printf("Output dimensions: %dx%d\n",$out_w,$out_h);

// Create blank (transparent) output image
$out=imagecreatetruecolor($out_w,$out_h);
imagesavealpha($out,true);
$trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($out, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($out, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

// Copy two source images into place on blank canvas
imagecopy($out, $im1, $im1_x, $im1_y, 0, 0, $im1_w, $im1_h);
imagecopy($out, $im2, $im2_x, $im2_y, 0, 0, $im2_w, $im2_h);

// Output and free from memory
imagepng($out,"result.png");

imagedestroy($im1);
imagedestroy($im2);
imagedestroy($out);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: than ks for the demo.  When I run it all I get is the size printed to screen.  How can I get the output you have from this code?

Comment: It's in the file called `result.png`.